# Create instance from same template as `this`?

Tags: c++, c++14

Let's assume I've got a base class `Base<T>` and a lot of `Sub1<T>`, ... `SubN<T>` which are subclasses of `Base`. `Base` has some kind of member function `foo` and in `foo` I need to create a new instance. But I'd like to always create the new instance from the same child template, but with a different template argument (`Sub1<T>::foo` -> `Sub1<U>`, `Sub2<T>::foo` -> `Sub2<U>`, ...).

For ex. `Sub1<float> a; auto b = a.foo();` so that `b` again would be a new `Sub1<int>` (even if `foo` is only overloaded on `Base`). Is this even possible? How would I do this?

Comment: You would need to have a "clone" virtual function and override it in every derived class.

Comment: I thought of that too, but that doesn't work if I'd might need to change the template parameters too.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. Do you want the same class or not? `Sub1<float>` and `Sub1<int>` are *entirely different* classes.

Comment: If you need to change the template parameters, then you can use a templated method inside the templated class. It would still need to be a virtual function as per @n.m. 's comment. If, however, you need to do that, I have to ask are you sure creating a new instance inside a class method is actually the most appropriate solution? Consider posting your initial problem and asking for a solution rather than asking for an implementation on your already chosen solution.

Comment: @patatahooligan Function templates cannot be virtual.

Comment: @Angew: How is the correct way to call `Sub1<float>` and `Sub1<int>` then? The same template? But yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @miho They're different instantiations of the same template. I'll try editing the Q, you can then fine-tune it (or revert).

Comment: If I'm understanding your question right (maybe you could post a code-ish example of what you want to do) you will run into the problem of not being able to create a virtual function template.  That means the base class can't call a virtual function _and_ pass a template parameter to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to implement the method in the `Base` class:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class D>
struct Base
{
    template <typename U, typename... Args>
    D<U>* foo(Args&&... args)
    {
        return new D<U>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived1 : Base<T, Derived1>
{
    // Implementation specific to Derived1
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived2 : Base<T, Derived2>
{
    // Implementation specific to Derived2
};

int main()
{
    Derived1<float> d1_float;
    Derived2<float> d2_float;

    auto d1_int = d1_float.foo<int>(); // has type Derived1<int>
    auto d2_int = d2_float.foo<int>(); // has type Derived2<int>

    return 0;
}
```

However, now `Derived1` and `Derived2` no longer share the same base class. So this is only useful if you use the base class to avoid code duplication and not for polymorphism.